# JavaScript value passing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Using SQLite I can list the values in

```
<div class="text-middle">
    <?php foreach($result as $row) ?> 
        <button class="button button1" id="myBtn" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" onclick="myFunction()"><?php echo $row['Id']; ?></button>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

However when I click on the button it's showing the only the first value in popup alert.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
    alert(x);
}
```

How can I get the corresponding values in each button?

Comment: Don't give all of your buttons the same id.

Comment: then how ? I dont know to create and fetch values using array

Comment: `document.getElementById` will only return 1 DOM element since the assumption is the ID is unique for each element.

Answer (score 6):

All of your buttons have the same `id` attribute. they must be unique within the page. To fix this you can remove the `id` attribute and pass the reference of the button to the function:

```
<div class="text-middle">
    <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?> 
        <button class="button button1" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" onclick="myFunction(this)"><?php echo $row['Id']; ?></button>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

```js
function myFunction(el) {
    var x = el.value;
    console.log(x);
}
```

Better still would be to place the same `class` on all the buttons and use unobtrusive JS code to attach your event handler, like this:

```
<div class="text-middle">
    <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?> 
        <button class="button" value="<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Id']; ?></button>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

```js
// native JS:
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button");    
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var x = this.value;
        console.log(x);
    });
}

// jQuery:
$('.button').click(function() {
    var x = this.value;
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: how to pass the same value in another function                      window.onload = function()           { var messageField = document.getElementById('message'); }    Here also am getting the same issue only showing one value

Comment: You've not really given enough information to help, so I'd start a new question for that. It could well be the same problem of duplicate id attributes though

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the same id for more then one element: id="myBtn"

Change your function:

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

to:

```
onclick="myFunction(this)"
```

And so:

```
function myFunction(element) {
      var x = element.value;
      alert(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the elements by their class, not by the id that they all share (which is a bad thing to do).

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("button1");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
    alert(x[i].value);
  }
}
</script>
```